# which languages are usually used to implement CAPTCHAs?

Tags: captcha

I am wondering which languages are mostly used to implement current CAPTCHAs.
Thanks alot,
Shadi.

Answer (score 1):

light is right.
Take Google's reCAPTCHA for example. It's available for the following technologies:

- PHP
- ASP.NET
- Classic ASP
- Java/JSP
- Perl
- WordPress
- MediaWiki
- phpBB
- FormMail
- Python
- Ruby
- ColdFusion
- WebDNA
- Movable Type
- Drupal
- Symfony
- TYPO3
- NucleusCMS
- vBulletin
- Joomla/Joomla Communtity Builder
- bbPress
- ExpressionEngine
- FlatPress
- PHPKIT
- and more

Look [here](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

almost any language can be used.  What you really want to look into is artificial intelligence.